# Separating state of elements matching selector in jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/7Uzhg/2/

I'm rewriting a jQuery plugin which displays subtitles from `.srt` files. The `div` that displays subtitles contains attributes `data-video` (the ID of the associated HTML5 Video object) and `data-srt` (a URL that contains the subtitles file).

The idea is that if I write

```
$('.srt').srt();
```

This will load and play the subtitles from all elements with the class srt.

There is a method in the jQuery plugin called `playSubtitles` which does the main job. This has an integer `currentSubtitle` which holds the index of the current subtitle to be played.

The problem is that if `$('.srt')` matches more than one element, they will both share the `currentSubtitle` variable, and I'm not sure how to separate those out.

Comment: You should attach the currentSubtitle value to each div.srt like $(theCurrentSrtElem).data('currentSubtitle',12)

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your plugin code with `each` so every selector have their own copy of that variable:

```
$.fn.srt = function() {
   return this.each(function() {
       var currentSubtitle;
       var self = $(this);
       return $.extend(self, {
           playSubtitles: function(...) {
               ...
           }
       });
   });
});
```